# Integral solutions to inverse trigonometric equation.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

The original question is this : I have to find number of ordered pairs of integral solutions to this :
$$\tan^{-1}{x} + \cos^{-1}{\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}} = \sin^{-1}{\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}} $$

I rearranged this as $\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{y}) = tan^{-1}{3} - \tan^{-1}x $

And then $\frac{1}{y}=\frac{3-x}{1+3x}$.

Finally reduced it to $$(1+3x).(1-3y)=-10xy$$

The problem is $-10xy = -1.2.5.x.y$

So, do I really have to check $32$ cases? I know some of them can be discarded easily, but still, checking all will take a lot of time.

My question is, is there a different method to solve this? Or is there an easier way to check the cases?

**Note** : The time constraint of the question is ideally 3-4 minutes. This is a question for IIT-JEE which is an entrance exam for engineering in India.

Comment: very interesting question; I'll try solving it tomorrow after my exam gets over. Which book did you come across this? I too am studying for IITJEE (Only in tenth though; will write it 2 years later). I've finished some calculus books and probability, but I'm revising for trig now... so the book recommendation would be great.

Comment: It was in the study material of the coaching class I go to. Do you do self study?

Comment: Indeed. Starting coaching from this year, but I'm comfortably paced for learning now. Any good book suggestions for solving Integrals (Extremely tough ones)? And if possible, could you mail me only the trig equation questions from your coaching class material? (By mailing it to philomathbau@gmail.com ) Sorry for troubling you; just that I think you can help me. And I think the answer for ordered pairs can be gotten from only 2*5 with sign differences...

Comment: @Kugelblitz It's in a hard copy, so I won't be able to mail it, sorry. I can send photos of some good questions :)

Comment: That would be great; please don't force yourself to do so if you don't have time...! If you give me your e-mail ID, I too can definitely send you some difficult questions I've come across (I assure you they'll be of high enough quality)

Comment: @Kugelblitz Turns out that email you provided doesn't exist? You might have made a typo

Comment: Sorry sorry.... I meant philomathbau5@gmail.com ...missed the 5 @ArpanBanerjee

Comment: @Kugelblitz I mailed you, have you seen?

Comment: I'm trying to create a site for "Indian Competitive Exams" and your question seems to be related to it, I think you would be interested to support it [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86609/indian-competitive-exams?referrer=uQtcXaMCGQOGlwjYmelKJA2) and spread the word to your friends?

Comment: @ADG I'll do my best.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23169/discussion-on-proposed-site-so-called-indian-competitive-exams

Comment: @Kugelblitz and Arpan, consider coming over [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math). You all might be interested since the above question relates to JEE.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+3x)(1-3y)+10xy=0$$
is equivalent to:
$$ 1+3x-3y+xy = 0 $$
or to:
$$ (y+3)(3-x)=10=\pm 1\cdot \pm 10 = \pm 2\cdot\pm 5. $$

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of trying to factorize it any other way :)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for confirming my doubt sir! @JackD'Aurizio (Impressive name you've got there, besides the math skills as evidenced by your answers in this community of course :) )

Comment: @Jack The answer given here is 2. Do the other answers contradict the initial question?

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee: no, the question answer is right. By converting the answer into an algebraic form we introduce spurious solutions, hence we have to check the solutions given by my last line.

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee While using the arctan subtraction formula , you are assuming x to be positive . Considering this , you will get two ordered pair : (8,-5) , (1,2).

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$\displaystyle \arctan x + \arccos\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right) = \arcsin \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$$

Now We can Write $$\displaystyle \arccos\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$ and $$\displaystyle \arcsin\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)=\arctan (3)$$

So Our equation is convert into $$\displaystyle \arctan (x)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)=\arctan(3)$$

So we can write it as $$\displaystyle \arctan \left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{y}}{1-\frac{x}{y}}\right)=\arctan(3)\Rightarrow \frac{xy+1}{y-x}=3$$

So our expression is $$\displaystyle y=\frac{3x+1}{3-x} = 3\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{3}}{3-x}\right).$$

Now If Given  $$\bf{x,y>0}$$ and $$\bf{x,y\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}\;,$$ Then $$y=\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{3}}{3-x}\right)>0$$

So We Get $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{3}<x<3$ and $x>0\;,$ Then we Get $0<x<3$

So Integer values of $x$ in This Interval are $x=1\;,2$

Now If $x=1\;,$ Then $\displaystyle y = \frac{3x+1}{3-x} = 2$ and If $x=2\;,$ Then $\displaystyle y=\frac{3x+1}{3-x} = 7$

So We get Only Two Positive Integer ordered pairs of $(x,y) = \left\{(1,2)\;\;,(2,7)\right\}$